# re-entrance safe async function execution

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, windows-runtime, promise, winrt-async

I have a `saveAsync` methods that can be called from several other parts of the app. Some of those code paths do not originate from the main UI thread but other async operations, like reading data from a socket/file.

In my `saveAsync` function I call `WinRT`'s `StorageFile` stream writing functions. Only one writer to a file is allowed at a time. So I have to queue up multiple successive calls to my `saveAsync` function and perform them sequentially. This is the code I am using right now:

```
SaveableMixin = {
  savesPending: 0,
  saveAsync: function() {
    self = this
    logger.debug("Save requested (_cachedFile=" + self._cachedFile + ")");
    if (self.saving) {
      self.savesPending += 1;
      logger.debug("saveAsync: already saving, " + self.savesPending + " pending now");
      return self.saving;
    }
    return self.saving = getFileNameAsync(self.serialNumber).then(function(file) {
      logger.debug("saveAsync: saving...");
      return self.node.ownerDocument.saveToFileAsync(file);
    }).then(null, (function(error) {
      return logger.error("saveAsync: failed but " + self.savesPending + " saves pending - good luck!", error);
    }).then((function() {
      logger.debug("saveAsync: saved and " + self.savesPending + " pending");
      self.saving = null;
      if (self.savesPending) {
        self.savesPending = 0;
        return self.saveAsync();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

CoffeeScript Original code:

```
savesPending: 0
saveAsync: () ->
  logger.debug("Save requested (_cachedFile=#{@_cachedFile})")
  if @saving
    @savesPending += 1
    logger.debug("saveAsync: already saving, #{@savesPending} pending now")
    return @saving
  @saving = getCachedFile(@serialNumber)
  .then (file) =>
    logger.debug("saveAsync: saving...")
    @node.ownerDocument.saveToFileAsync(file)
  .then null, (error) =>
    logger.error("saveAsync: failed with inspection #{@serialNumber} but #{@savesPending} saves pending - good luck!", error)
  .then =>
    logger.debug("saveAsync: saved and #{@savesPending} pending")
    @saving = null
    if @savesPending
      @savesPending = 0
      return @saveAsync()
```

As you can see I remember the last `saving` promise to know that an operation is running. However it can happen, that I still get an `Access Denied` exception cause somehow, some code paths manage to both see `saving` as being empty and therefore thinking now save operation is ongoing. It seems to happen when the variable is just about to be assigned for the first caller, when a second async operation (socket read for example) finishes and also calls `saveAsync` while the first caller gets the `saving` variable assigned.

In C++ I would use locks to prevent that. What can be done in the JavaScript world?

## Update

```
_saving: WinJS.Promise.as(),
_saves: 0,
saveAsync: function() {
    var currentSave;
    currentSave = this._saves;
    this._saves += 1;
    return this._saving = this._saving.then((function(_this) {
      return function() {
        logger.debug("saveAsync: get file for save " + currentSave);
        return getCachedFile(_this.serialNumber);
      };
    })(this)).then((function(_this) {
      return function(file) {
        logger.debug("saveAsync: got file for save " + currentSave + " ...");
        return _this.node.ownerDocument.saveToFileAsync(file);
      };
    })(this)).then(null, function(error) {
      logger.debug("saveAsync: error for " + currentSave);
    });
```

This yield the following output in the debugger:

```
2014-12-07 23:46:52,286 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: get file for save 0
2014-12-07 23:46:52,289 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: get file for save 0
2014-12-07 23:46:52,349 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: got file for save 0 ...
2014-12-07 23:46:52,444 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: got file for save 0 ...
2014-12-07 23:46:52,446 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: get file for save 1
2014-12-07 23:46:52,447 - [inspection - DEBUG] - saveAsync: got file for save 1 ...
```

and of course that's a double access to the file in question and crashes with an AV.

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of the issue, but you are not closing your parenthesis properly. Throw this code into a jslinter or soemthing, you'll see that some parenthesis are left open.

Comment: thanks, the code was hand-edited from its coffeescript source by me, and I removed some clutter. So yea, some parenthesis might not be closed correctly.

Comment: That `self` is missing a `var` stems from the coffee cleanup as well? You might want to post the original coffeescript as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how that queuing is supposed to work. `savesPending` is incremented every time a request is issued while a save is still ongoing, but where is the accompanying data (`.serialNumber`?) stored? And why is `savesPending` reset to 0, instead of being decremented? Please elaborate :-)

Comment: @Bergi the .serialNumber is a member of the class you mix this class in with. I increment `savesPending` only to know that while the file is saved, there have been more requests to save it. Since all of those requests, in the end, save the latest state of the XML, I only need to know if there are pending saves and save the file one more time. I could have used a boolan instead of incrementing the counter, but so I can see how many calls I got during a save.

Comment: Ah, I see. So when you only care about the latest state, can't you just abort the current write operation before starting another one?

Comment: So `.saveToFileAsync` is the throwing operation, and multiple (mixed-in) instances can have the same `.node.ownerDocument`?

Comment: @Bergi there is only one instance that has the `.node.ownerDocument`. Its just that there are multiple function in the instance that can be called at any time, that perform async operations and after each operation call the instances saveAsync method to persist the state of the model.

Comment: Well, but those are locked fine with the `.saving` flag on the instance, that's why I guessed that the lock isn't bound 1-1 to the resource. The only other explanation I come up with would be that `saveToFileAsync` does have its own lock, but resolves that only after having executed its callback. A stacktrace from the exception, and possibly the code of `saveToFileAsync` could shed some light on that.

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript world you would use promises to do that, a promise abstracts a sequence of async operations and you can use it as a queue.

```
SaveableMixin = {
  queue: WinJS.promise.as(), // empty start of queue
  saveAsync: function() {
    this.queue = this.queue.then(function(){ // update the queue
      return getFileNameAsync(self.serialNumber).then(function(file) {
          logger.debug("saveAsync: saving...");
          return self.node.ownerDocument.saveToFileAsync(file);
    })..then(null, (function(error) {
      return logger.error("saveAsync: failed good luck!", error);
    }).then((function() {
      logger.debug("saveAsync: saved and " + self.savesPending + " pending");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This might have the same race-condition I am currently experiencing. The moment "n" where this.queue is assigned, another completion handler might call saveAsync and assign this.queue to something different. No?

Comment: @philk Fun fact - JavaScript in most contexts and in WinJS apps in particular is _single threaded_. It's event based and single threaded in those contexts. No two assignments can occur at the same time.

Comment: I thought so too. But then my code would already work, wouldn't it?
I can see the stack trace from methods entering the saveAsync method, and they all come from the main thread, yes. Yet, it can happen that its tried to write to the file from 2 different code paths at once.

Comment: One clarification: the UI thread in JavaScript is single-threaded, but WinRT async operations *do* get delegated to other threads. The callbacks to completed/error/progress handlers from those other threads will come onto the UI thread, so you can process results from only one operation at a time, but multiple operations can be happening simultaneously and thus have collisions.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT the JavaScript is single threaded though, isn't it? I mean, just like in Node - the other stuff that runs in the other threads isn't the userland code.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT right about the WinRT async operations. Now, do you have a solution to the problem? Checked your book already of course ;)

Comment: I'm thinking you could employ something along the lines of the sequential promises with sequential results pattern described in Appendix A on page 1208. It starts with an array of inputs, but the important part is starting the next async operation inside the completed handler of the previous. Could you basically manage a queue inside an array, and just take the next one from the front of the list upon each completion?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have updated my code according to your answer. It still runs into race conditions. Please see the update section in my OP.